# Return numbers only from string

Tags: google-bigquery

How to return only the numbers from string in google big query, example:

I tried REGEXP_EXTRACT and no results.

'hello 1234 hello'  --> 1234

Thanks
Ariel

Comment: please share your code, what you tried and what doesn't work. possibly even some error messages, sample input AND output would be super helpful. the lack of this info is causing your question to be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  txt, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, r'\D', '') AS all_numbers_together,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, r'\D', 'x'), r'x+', ' ') AS all_numbers_separated
FROM
(SELECT 'hello 1234 hello' AS txt),
(SELECT '111 hello 1234 hello 222' AS txt)
```

Comment: Thanks but i get an error message: Incorrect syntax near "\D"

Comment: what exactly you tried? you run exactly what I gave you or something else? To eliminate uncertainty  - try `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('hello 1234 hello', r'\D', '') AS all_numbers_together`